# Javascript append is adding child to parent via console but not showing in dev tools elements or on page

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I am attempting to add a child node to an existing container.  Looking at dev tools, after clicking the button, I see that in my console log my parent container (parking_container) indeed has the div appended.

In the elements section of dev tools, the parking container does not show the appended div.  On the page itself, I do not see the appended div.  If I edit the html in elements directly and add the div as shown in the console log, it does show as expected.

EDIT: Context:  I am attempting a hot-fix on a website built in drupal.  The page section I am trying to attempt to append the node to is a custom module.  I am able to add an "html" module, which is where I am inserting the code below.  Again, the button shows and runs the script as expected, and it appears that the append is adding the div via the console log, but not showing on the page.  I understand that the problem may be something a) out of my control with this method or b) not solvable without giving context that I can't give.

Just hoping someone maybe has an idea.  Thanks.

```
<button onclick="addElement()">Click me</button>


<script>
function addElement (){ 
  var pContainer = document.getElementById("parking_container");

  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
      newDiv.innerHTML="Temporary Filler";

  pContainer.appendChild(newDiv);

  console.log(pContainer);
 } 

</script>
```

Comment: _“What am I missing?”_ - what an actual [mre] should look like. Please provide one, without seeing this in context, it is impossible to tell what is going on.

Comment: Put your script in a file, and load that file with `<script src="..." async defer></script>` so that you can at least rule out "it runs before the DOM is done". `defer` tells the browser to only execute this code _after_ your DOM tree has been fully build. Also, don't use `.innerHTML` when you're setting text, use `.textContent` instead.

Comment: Maybe you made one of the rather typical beginner’s mistakes, and used the ID `parking_container` on more than one element? Then what you are actually appending the element to, and what you are looking at in the element panel, might be different things.

Comment: Trying to recreate your code in jsfiddle made it work. https://jsfiddle.net/6vuLybte/
Please provide more details because with the current info I cannot see what could be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var node = document.createTextNode("Temporary Filler");
newDiv.appendChild(node);
pContainer.appendChild(newDiv);
```

instead of

```
newDiv.innerHTML="Temporary Filler";
```